# Exhaust Fan for Bathroom

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I am planning on replacing the exhaust fans in my bathroom.  I think original are typical low cost/quality builder selections (Harbor Breeze from Lowes Depot), but I would like to get a better make.  Are there known quality choices, or are they all pretty much the same?

Comment: Quite a few review sites.  This sounds more like shopping than fixing/installing question.

Comment: Agree that this is a shopping/opinion question; vtc. (But Panasonic.)

Comment: Ahhh...it is kinda like shopping. (although I was trying to leverage other's experience, since actual shopping is impossible to make a decision through all of the marketing lies and noise nowadays.)  I see the question is closed, so good.  Sorry for the distraction :--)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some brands are *in general* better than others. But what I generally recommend is to shop based on *specifications* primarily. For bathroom exhaust fans, that means:

- Features - fan only, fan + light, fan + light + heat? If including heat, checking the requirements is important as some require a 20A circuit and some only a 15A circuit.
- Speed - usually measured in CFM, higher is better.
- Sound - usually measured in Sones, lower is better.
- Installation requirements - particularly ductwork, as *not* having to run a new duct can be a big plus.
- Automatic humidity sensor - used to be rare, now quite common, but can also be done at the switch.